# JQuery tooltip that is not tied to an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any jquery plugin that enables you to programmatically call a tooltip that will show up under the mouse?

Why I am looking for this is because I have a pie graph made with jquery flot. You can have it call a function when hovering a field in the pie, so this essentially has to be called from a function, and NOT tied to an object on the page.

Thanks in advance, I couldn't really find anything on google searching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the cursormessage plugin?

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/CursorMessage

Alternatively you could try combining clueTip's `sticky` and `mouse follow` options:

http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/

Comment: No, I have not! cursormessage was exactly was I was looking for, thank you very much! :)